# Entity Framework & ASP.NET MVC: can't get to the [HttpPost] on my controller from another one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to redirect the user from this view on the `SolicitantesController` to the one on the `Create` of `ExpedientesController`:

```
@model Entrega02Programacion03.Models.Solicitante

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InformeSolicitante";
}

<h2>InformeSolicitante</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Solicitante</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
       <dd>Cedula:  @ViewBag.Cedula </dd> 
      <dd> Nombre: @ViewBag.Nombre</dd>
       <dd>Apellido: @ViewBag.Apellido</dd>
       <dd>Email:  @ViewBag.Email</dd>
       <dd>Tel: @ViewBag.tel</dd>
    </dl>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Expediente" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the post on `solicitantesController`, but I can't get my button `Crear Expediente` to get there, any ideas of what I may be doing wrong? Thanks

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InformeSolicitantes()
{
     return RedirectToAction("Expedientes", "Create");
}
```

Comment: Try putting it inside a <form> tag then set the action to InformeSolicitantes

Comment: The is no point having a submit button without the form. But you are not editing anything, nor changing data in the POST method, so neither a form or submit button is appropriate. Just use a link and redirect to your `Create()` method in `ExpedientesController`

Comment: tks, what I ended up doing was just having a function that redirect to the appropriate controller , and I call that function on the button on the view

Answer (score 0):

i suggest two solutions to solve it:

1)replace **submit html control** with anchor link with **InformeSolicitantes** action url and remove [HttpPost]

for example replace

```
<input type="submit" value="Crear Expediente" class="btn btn-default" />
```

with

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="action path/name"></a>
```

then remove

`[HttpPost]`

2)put input control into form control and set form action and controllers to hit **InformeSolicitantes** action.

for example replace

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear Expediente" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<form action="action path/name" method="post"><div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear Expediente" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div></form>
```